# Session Clustering a Grails app in Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, grails, groovy, load-balancing

Has any one done it yet? I am having class loader problems de-serializing the grails session object.

Here is the error:

WARN net.spy.memcached.transcoders.SerializingTranscoder:  Caught CNFE 
decoding 1168 bytes of data 
     [exec] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.myapp.User 
     [exec]     at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.RootLoader.findClass 
(RootLoader.java:156) 
     [exec]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:319) 
     [exec]     at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.RootLoader.loadClass 
(RootLoader.java:128) 
     [exec]     at 
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsRootLoader.loadClass 
(GrailsRootLoader.java:43) 
     [exec]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:254) 
     [exec]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal 
(ClassLoader.java:402) 
     [exec]     at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) 
     [exec]     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247) 
     [exec]     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.resolveClass 
(ObjectInputStream.java:604) 
     [exec]     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc 
(ObjectInputStream.java:1575) 
     [exec]     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc 
(ObjectInputStream.java:1496) 
     [exec]     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject 
(ObjectInputStream.java:1732) 
     [exec]     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0 
(ObjectInputStream.java:1329) 
     [exec]     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject 
(ObjectInputStream.java:351) 
     [exec]     at 
net.spy.memcached.transcoders.BaseSerializingTranscoder.deserialize 
(BaseSerializingTranscoder.java:100) 
     [exec]     at 
net.spy.memcached.transcoders.SerializingTranscoder.decode 
(SerializingTranscoder.java:66)

Answer (score 1):

I guess there is no easy way to fix it since Grails is using a custom classloader to load the domain classes (I assume the com.myapp.User class is a domain class). As a workaround you could store just store the id of the user in the session and use a technique like I've described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503279/accessing-the-model-from-a-layout-view-in-grails/503535#503535) to retrieve it on every request. This would also provide the benefit of reducing the size of the session that needs to be replicated.

Comment: I think its a good idea if it was the only Groovy object in session and could be recovered from second instance of Tomcat from persistent store. But mine is a complicated app and uses a mix of Groovy and Java ,and has all sorts of objects in session (which in itself is a problem

Answer (score 0):

I've only ever used sticky sessions via an apache mod_proxy setup so have never tried sharing session data across nodes. Is that an option for you?

Comment: I am already doing the loadbalancing, but I need to go a step further now.

Answer (score 0):

I've the same CNFE problem while using SpyMemcached in development environment. The CNFE(ClassNotFoundException) of SpyMemcached, is mainly generated by the multi ClassLoader in a JVM. Search this article: http://code.google.com/p/spymemcached/issues/detail?id=155 , find:

> "I had this issue in the past and I found a solution. The occurs
>   because the memcached client it is loaded using a classloader and the
>   serialized object class is loaded using another classloader. "

So, in my case, I just move the memcached-VERSION.jar from ext-lib dir to app-lib dir(/WEB-INF/lib).  Then the memcached client and the app classes are all in the same ClassLoader,  and this exception is cleared.