# Override Grails <g:set> variable's value in a <g:layoutBody>

Tags: grails, gsp

I have a `layout.gsp` where I define some markup for a control (say, banner) that might be displayed on any page (or might not).

```
<g:set var="showBanner" value="${...}" scope="page|request|flash|session"/>
<!-- Some more logic that may g:set showBanner var -->

<g:layoutBody/>

<g:if test="${[flash|request|???].showBanner}">
   <div id="banner">...</div>
</g:if>
```

The idea is to let the page, rendered by `<g:layoutBody>`, to decide if it wants the banner on it or not. So, one page may decide to always show banner, as following - `page1.gsp:`

```
<g:set var="showBanner" value="${true}" scope="page|request|flash|session"/>
```

Another page decides to never show banner on it, as following - `page2.gsp:`

```
<g:set var="showBanner" value="${false}" scope="page|request|flash|session"/>
```

Unfortunately, this approach doesn't work for me. I tried all different combinations of `scope` attribute and still cannot have it overridden in children pages.

Is this a wrong approach in general or I miss some detail?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found what I was doing wrong. The issue is that variables set inside included page are evaluated *before* the `layout.gsp` code runs, not at the moment of `<g:layoutBody/>` tag insertion (or *call*).

In other words, dependencies are rendered before the layout, not at the moment layout directive is encountered. This may be intuitive for some, but not for others (not for me).

Another point is that you still need to use `request` scope to access the same var between pages (which is quite intuitive).

So, the solution becomes:

First in `page1.gsp`:

```
<g:set var="showBanner" value="${true}" scope="request"/>
```

Then in `layout.gsp`:

```
<!-- Doesn't matter were you put it, always evaluated first -->
<g:layoutBody/>

<g:if test="request.showBanner == null"> <!-- if not set by children page -->
    <g:set var="showBanner" value="${...}" scope="request"/>
    <!-- Some more logic that may g:set request.showBanner var -->
</g:if>

<g:if test="${request.showBanner}">
   <div id="banner">...</div>
</g:if>
```

Answer (score 0):

What about you set the variable inside an interceptor?  Like one shown here: [Accessing the model from a layout view in Grails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503279/accessing-the-model-from-a-layout-view-in-grails)